# Rails - Filter the results if they match the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `ManytoMany` association setup between Model `User` and `Tag`, suppose if I do

```
users = User.all
```

This will give me all the users, I want to filter these records if they are in `ManyToMany` association with lets say `tag_id` `55`

For a single object I know I can do `users.first.tags.exists?(55)` and this will give `true` or `false` bot how do I perform this on a `users` which contains 100's of record?
My questions are

1. Is using loop the only way to achieve this?
2. How to remove to records from `users` where the relationship does not exist?
3. I have hundreds of records in `users` so I need to do this in a way it does not effect the performance.

I will really appreciate any feedback on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the tag id 55 of user in this way

```
@user = User.joins(:tags).where("tags.id = ?" ,55)
```

OR

```
@user = User.includes(:tags).where(tags: {id: 55})
```

You can also filter for multiple ids of tag in this way

```
tags_id = [55,56,57,58,59]
@user = User.joins(:tags).where("tags.id IN = (?)" ,tags_id)
```

You can find whether associations is exists or not with this query

```
User.includes(:tags).where( :tags => { :id => nil } ).
```

It will give all users who dont have any tags.

Comment: Could you please explain what is going on here?

Comment: So it will join 2 tables user and tag. it is standard query by rails. It is used for better performance. it will fetch all records in one query.

Comment: @Saadia You can accept this answer if it is helpful to you

Comment: I will when I understand what is going on if this helped in what i am doing

Comment: @Saadia Yes sure. You can run this query in your console. and can show query . so you have better idea.

Comment: I am not getting any record in console all i see is #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3fdff4be9a9c>, the example i followed was third from the top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149360/discussion-between-saadia-and-vishal).